# Why is the IP address of the Google DNS server the only one, which is returning open ports in my case?

Tags: android, kotlin, network-programming

I am creating a port scanner of a selected IP address, for my Android app. I use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nc [host] [port]") to scan ports. My scanner only tests the top 100 ports, separately for TCP and UDP. Depending on the code for this process, I consider the port open or closed ("0" means the process was successful, so the port is open, any other number means failure).

```
override fun run() {
            val response: String
            val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
            val process = runtime.exec("nc $host $port")
            
            process.waitFor()

            if (process.isAlive) {
                process.destroy()
                response = "$host:$port is closed"
            } else {
                val code = process.exitValue()
                if (code == 0) {
                    response = "$host:$port is open"
                } else {
                    response = "$host:$port is closed"
                }
            }
        }
```

This method turned out to be only partially effective. When the host address is "8.8.8.8" or "8.8.4.4", the algorithm displays ports 53 and 443 for tcp as open. According to the Internet, this is true, so this case is successful. However, any other IP address returns all ports as closed, with a code of 1. These are both local network addresses and "global" addresses (sorry if I missed lingo). I should mention, that whole thing is running on separate threads, through executor service. It shouldn't matter though, result was the same with only one thread.

If all cases were unsuccessful, I would consider this a failure and try another solution, e.g. with the Socket class. However, the success at these two addresses haunts me. As you can read, I am not experienced in computer networks, protocols and the OSI model.

Do you know where the difference in the outcome of these cases comes from?

Comment: Ahh, my bad. I mistakenly wrote 80, instead of 53. But yeah, I meant 53

Comment: But regarding 443. according to this website, 443 should be open on 8.8.8.8 : https://dnslytics.com/ip/8.8.8.8

Comment: Port 443 may be blocked by Cloudflare und similar protectors because the used software is not known (or disallowed) by their TLS fingerprinting software. Especially languages like Python are often blocked as they can be used for page scraping.

Comment: @Robert, DNS also uses TCP port 53. From the beginning it was supposed to be that way, but some implementations did not do it correctly, so _[RFC 5966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5966.html)_ made it explicit: "_This document therefore updates the core DNS protocol specifications such that support for TCP is henceforth a REQUIRED part of a full DNS protocol implementation._"